# Java Reader Implementation

Tags: java, stream

I have exercise in java like "define text stream(**Reader**) that will clear from whitespaces". I checked **Reader** and It only requires to implement 2 methods:

```
@Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

I am little confused what should I really do. From what I understand `cbuf` is destination, so from what should I read?

Comment: You should probably ask whoever gave you the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

A class extending [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) will have an underlying data source (see [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) for example which, as you might guess, reads text from a `String` object).

In your assignment the objective is to create a reader that will strip all the whitespaces from that data source (implement, for example, a `StringReader` that never writes whitespaces into the target `char[]` array).